# How to address (hidden) volume for vssadmin

Tags: windows, windows-10, volume-shadow-copy

I have a volume named like this

```
\\?\Volume{fc3a230-ef05-d9875-c2fa-3aacteb234}\
```

How can I address this in the following command

```
vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=\\?\Volume{fc3a230-ef05-d9875-c2fa-3aacteb234}\ /On=C: /MaxSize=UNBOUNDED
```

I get errors like *invalid option* or *the given volume shadow copy association was not found*. Or do I don't have access to it?

Answer (score 1):

#### I get errors like *invalid option* or *the given volume shadow copy association was not found*.

`vssadmin resize shadowstorage ...` requires a drive specification. For example:

```
vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=C: /on=C: /maxsize=50GB
```

Where:

```
/for=C: /on=C:
```

Tells Windows that the VSS storage is on the C drive, change the letter to match your environment.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [vssadmin](https://ss64.com/nt/vssadmin.html) - Display the current volume shadow copy backups and all installed shadow copy writers and providers.

Comment: And if one of the volumes doesn't have a mapped drive name like `C:` or `D:`? It only appears to have this cryptic name `\\?\Volume{fc3a230-ef05-d9875-c2fa-3aacteb234}\` ...

Comment: @testing No idea :/

Comment: You can use subst to map a driveletter to it temporarily.